# Faking protected members with Moq, with ability to call them directly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

So, is there a better way to do something like this using Moq?

```
public class Mom{

    protected virtual Love DoLove(){
        ...
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MomTests{

   class FakeMom:Mom{
      public new Love DoLove(){
         return base.DoLove();
      }
   }

   [Test]
   public void DoLove_Test(){
      var fakeM = new FakeMom();
      Assert(_expectedLove,fakeM.DoLove());
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not just treat the `protected` method as any other method you can't call directly, and either change the accessibility or test the side-effects of accessible calls? (If you're using InternalsVisibleTo, you could just change it to `protected internal`, perhaps.)

Comment: Moq should mock external objects so that you can isolate your SuT. In this case all you have is the SuT. So I am tempted to say: no, Moq would not help you out here. PS: nothing wrong with your solution. I'd do the same in this case.

Comment: OMG... Jon Skeet! He's real... woaaaaaaa